# How do I make a TikZ graphic with small sans serif font?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, sans-serif

I want the font in the graphic to be sans serif, and to be smaller than the main document. I tried

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (5, 5) node[midway] {I am a rectangle}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem is that the `font=\small` option within the figure overrides the `\font=\sffamily` option from the picture declaration and I end up with a small serif font. How do I set both the font size and font family at once?

Comment: Put `\sffamily` prior to `\begin{tikzpicture}`

Comment: off-toppic ... `\tikzstyle` is depreciated, instead it use  `\tikzset`

Comment: @Zarko thank you, this is my first tikz graphic and I am simply using whatever advice I can find on the Internet, that's where I saw \tikzstyle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Invoke `\sffamily` before entering `tikz`, or
2. You can combine `\small` and `\sffamily` in the same `font=` directive.

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
{\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tikzset{every node}=[font=\small]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (5, 5) node[midway] {I am a rectangle};
\end{tikzpicture}}

No longer in sffamily

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \tikzset{every node}=[font=\small\sffamily]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (5, 5) node[midway] {I am a rectangle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realize I can use two assignments in the same `\font=` option. I will use the second one, as the first one changes it for the rest of the document and enclosing the graphic in `\textsf{}` broke the whole thing.

Comment: @rumtscho You can limit the scope of the `\sffamily` by enclosing the affected code in braces `{}`, as I edited to show in the first case.

Answer (score 4):

Option `font` and `node font` can be combined:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
  \draw[node font=\small]
    (0,0) rectangle (4, 2) node[midway] {I am a rectangle};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Also, an option `add to font` can be defined to put additional font settings to the current setting of option `font` as shown in the following example, which includes the code from above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
% Definition of option "font" in "tikz.code.tex":
%   \tikzoption{font}{\def\tikz@textfont{#1}}
% New TikZ option "add to font":
\tikzoption{add to font}{%
  \providecommand*{\tikz@textfont}{}%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@textfont\expandafter{%
    \tikz@textfont
    #1%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
  \draw[node font=\small]
    (0,0) rectangle (4, 2) node[midway] {I am a rectangle};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
  \draw[add to font=\small]
    (0,0) rectangle (4, 2) node[midway] {I am a rectangle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]